# Total Occurances of Mutiple Words/Values in File

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a file that contains a large amount of text. I am reading this file, and intend to print out the number of times a Bible passage is referenced, noted by a line starting with "Verse". I then want to print out the reference followed by the number of occurrences.

Example file:

```
Verse- Matthew 5:2
Commentary- Matthew
Verse- Matthew 10:5
Verse- John 3:16
Commentary- John
Verse- Luke 5:2
Commentary- Luke
```

Results should be something like this:

```
{'5:2': 2, '10:5': 1, '3:16': 1}
```

I am using a dictionary to make a key:value of reference:occurrences. The script is short and provided:

```
fileHandle = open("sj", "r")
occurrences = dict()
references = []
#Go through each line if it is a verse line (starts with "Verse"), seperate the reference and count the reference
for line in fileHandle:
    if "Verse" in line:
        verseLine = line.split()
        references.append(verseLine[2]) #Reference is always 3rd index
        for reference in references:
            if reference not in occurrences:
                occurrences[reference] = 1
            else:
                occurrences[reference] = occurrences[reference] + 1
print(" References printed below ")
print(references)
print(" Occerances printed below ")
print(occurrences)
```

**Problem:** The references are being counted in a weird way. This is my output:

```
{'5:2': 5, '10:5': 3, '3:16': 2}
```

Obviously that's not right! It's something to do with the `else:` statement I think. For example, if I change it to `occurrences[reference] = occurrences[reference] + 2` (note the 1 changed to a 2) then I expect the results to double. But they don't:

`{'5:2': 9, '10:5': 5, '3:16': 3}`

Why is this tally not counting correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `references`  list is being processed for every line with a `"Verse"` string so the script is overcounting.

Move the `references` loop out of the `line` loop.

```py
fileHandle = open("sj", "r")
occurrences = dict()
references = []
#Go through each line if it is a verse line (starts with "Verse"), seperate the reference and count the reference
for line in fileHandle:
    if "Verse" in line:
        verseLine = line.split()
        references.append(verseLine[2]) #Reference is always 3rd index

# After indexing every verse you can start counting them
for reference in references:
    if reference not in occurrences:
        occurrences[reference] = 1
    else:
        occurrences[reference] = occurrences[reference] + 1

print(" References printed below ")
print(references)
print(" Occerances printed below ")
print(occurrences)
```

Unless you need the list of references for further processing this is an improved version of your script:

```
fileHandle = open("sj", "r")
occurrences = dict()

#Go through each line if it is a verse line (starts with "Verse"), seperate the reference and count the reference
for line in fileHandle:
    if "Verse" in line:
        verseLine = line.split()
        try:
            occurrences[verseLine[2]] += 1
        except KeyError:
            occurrences[verseLine[2]] = 1

fileHandle.close()
print(" References printed below ")
print(references)
print(" Occerances printed below ")
print(occurrences)
```

Comment: Accepted because first line directly and quickly answered the simple error. Thank you for the additional feedback to improve the script!

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few improvements suggestions for your code:

- use `with open('test.txt') as f` so you don't forget to close the file at the end
- use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for the counting job
- do you want to use only chapter and verse numbers, or should you also include the book name?

My code:

```
import collections
c = collections.Counter()

with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if len(line) > 0:
            if line.startswith('Verse'):
                data = line[6:]               # Book, chapter and verse number
                # data = line.split()[2]      # only chapter and verse number

                c.update({data: 1})

print('all:')
for k, count in c.items():
    print(' ', count, k)

print('most common:')
for k, count in c.most_common(1):
    print(' ', count, k)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another version using `re` and `collections.Counter`:

```
data = '''Verse- Matthew 5:2
Commentary- Matthew
Verse- Matthew 10:5
Verse- John 3:16
Commentary- John
Verse- Luke 5:2
Commentary- Luke'''

import re
from collections import Counter

c = Counter( re.findall(r'^Verse.*?(\d+:\d+)$', data, flags=re.M) )
print(dict(c))
```

Prints:

```
{'5:2': 2, '10:5': 1, '3:16': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the fixed code

```
fileHandle = open("sj", "r")
occurrences = dict()
references = []
# Go through each line if it is a verse line (starts with "Verse"), seperate the reference and count the reference
for line in fileHandle:
    if line.startswith("Verse"):
        verseLine = line.split()
        try:
            occurrences[verseLine[2]] += 1  # Reference is always 3rd index
        except KeyError:
            occurrences[verseLine[2]] = 1
print(" References printed below ")
print(references)
print(" Occerances printed below ")
print(occurrences)
```

I think this happens because you increment the occurrence value of **all of the references**, for **each** line that contains `'Verse'`. (note that I changed `"Verse" in line` to `line.startswith("Verse"), so the code will only execute if the line starts with`"Verse"`.